# get file content and assign to property in Phing

Tags: phing

Is there a way to get a file content and assign to property for Phing?

An equivalent to ant:

```
<project name="foobar" default="foo">
   <target name="foo">
     <loadfile property="foo.bar" srcFile="foobar/moo.txt"/>
     <echo>${foo.bar}</echo>
   </target>
</project>
```

?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There may be a simpler alternative.

Comment: i want to load a content and check if specific string is there. Thanks Steve

Comment: How about using an exec task to grep for it. Depending on what you want for a return value you may want to look at the test command.

Comment: could do, but i was thinking maybe there is a build in task. At the end i exec cat command, assign that to variable and did comparison. Cheers Steve

Comment: you should answer your own question as an aid to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the [`loadfile`](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apbs24.html) task do what you're after?

Comment: The documentation has moved to here: [loadfiletask @ phing.info](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apbs21.html)